# Creating CSR with OpenSSL hangs

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate, command-prompt

I'm trying to create batch file for WINDOWS to automate creation of self-signed certificate.
Following this tutorial:
http://www.xenocafe.com/tutorials/linux/centos/openssl/self_signed_certificates/index.php

I wrote following script:

```
@echo off

REM This script takes name passed in and generates private and public keys using OpenSSL
REM First parameter expects name
IF "%1"=="" GOTO EXIT

ECHO Generating PRIVATE key ------------------------------
openssl genrsa -des3 -out %1.key 1024

ECHO Creating certificate sign request (CSR) -------------
openssl req -key %1.key -out %1.csr

ECHO Signing CSR 100 years -------------------------------
openssl x509 -req -days 36500 -in %1.csr -signkey %1.key -out %1.crt

ECHO Create a kopy of password-protected key -------------
cp %1.key %1.key.secure

ECHO Remove password from private key --------------------
openssl rsa -in %1.key.secure -out %1.key
```

Idea is to get private key with no password and public key for distribution. I run CMD prompt under admin rights and here is what I get:

[image]

Just hands there, doesn't ask about country code, etc..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It should have `-new`:

```
ECHO Creating certificate sign request (CSR) -------------
openssl req -new -key %1.key -out %1.csr
```

Answer (score 32):

I had the same issue, 6 months ago, using `GitBash` in Windows 7, After hours of search this solved my issue:

```
winpty openssl genrsa -out ../private.pem -aes256 4096
```

Let me know if it helps anyone.

Comment: This helped me when using `GitBash` on Windows Server 2012 R2.

Comment: To me also helped to run bash inside windows console rather than mintty

Comment: Prefixing `winpty` fixed all hanging `openssl` commands in my GitBash!

Comment: Same issue on Win10 and latest `GitBash`, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

putting winpty infront of my generate command stopped it from hanging

```
winpty openssl genrsa -aes256 -out clientprivate.key 2048
```

Comment: Isn't this just what Zuhayer Tahir said back in 2017? If you're adding some extra information that isn't in the existing answer, please edit to make that clearer, otherwise you're likely to be downvoted.